# jRecorder stops working after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback, jrecorder

I'm using jRecorder on an ASP.net page that has a dropdown with autopostback.
After postback, the jRecorder stops working.
After looking up the problem, I understood that the jquery script should be rerun after the postback, but I'm not too familiar with jquery and not sure how to do it.

**EDIT:**
I've moved the jquery code into a pageLoad function, but now after postback, when I press record, I receive the error message:  Object doesn't support property or method 'jStartRecording'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my problem by using an iframe. It's not ideal and flickers on each postback, but at least it does the job, until a better solution comes up.